# Type for function that accepts module containing specific function?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to use a more functional syntax, and I've got two modules:

```py
# foo.py

def bar():
  # Do something
  pass
```

```py
# baz.py

def baz(qux: ???):
   qux.bar()

# Usage:
import foo as Foo
import baz

baz(Foo)
```

I want `baz` to accept an argument (`qux`) which has an an attribute `bar` which is a callable. This parameter could refer to a module, or an instance of some class - I don't really care. Is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a very unusual thing to do. While it's possible, we don't usually pass modules around dynamically.

Comment: You can define "a thing we could call `bar` on" with a [protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), if that's what you mean.

Comment: What would a protocol look like? I've tried that using a class that extends Protocol, and type errors were thrown like: argument of type "foo.py" is not a MyProtocol.

Comment: "Having an attribute with a given name" is not part of an object's type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), as mentioned by @jonrsharpe in the comments:

```py
# baz.py

from typing import Protocol


class SupportsBar(Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> None:
        ...


def baz(qux: SupportsBar) -> None:
    qux.bar()


# Usage:
import foo as Foo

baz(Foo)  # no errors
```